# Meteor.call() one method per time restriction, or async method call blocking another methods

Tags: meteor

I have a rather long-running background task that I call with Meteor.call() from frontend and then through called server-side method. This task returns a value eventually. Application don't really care about this value, success or error, but still like to eventually pop up successful message (with alertify, but it isn't related to question).

Method use futures, so it is async.

```
myQueueMethod: function(data) {
  var future = new Future();
  // do things, then future.return or future.throw
  return future.wait();
}
```

If I call this method, it blocks any other server-side method calls until future returns or throw. This approach isn't desirable. Any suggestions?

Comment: I hardly ever use a future explicitly, check out these samples (including `unblock`) for a better understanding of methods: https://github.com/meteorinaction/ch10-advancedservermethods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.unblock()` is meant to do that:

```
myQueueMethod: function(data) {
  var future = new Future();
  this.unblock();
  // do things, then future.return or future.throw
  return future.wait();
}
```

Here's [the documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/method_unblock).

Answer (score 2):

what you also could do is, create a "service" collection and subscribe to that via server publish method.

When call Meteor.method() immidiate return from that function with only true/false, when task is placed. On Server you may run a long term process and insert the data afterwards in that collection.

So on client you are "listen" or "observe" to that changes and receive the result if there is one.

To get an idea of what I am talking about, have a look at:

[MeteorPad Playground 1](http://meteorpad.com/pad/i7ec92p45kswPF89E/Sample_Publish_to_Local-Collection_via_observe)

[MeteorPad Playground 2](http://meteorpad.com/pad/Zq4QdMW84rKGersFH/Sample_Publish_to_Local-Collection_Reactive_way)

This would completly decouple your processing.

Cheers
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Just a side note, `return` is a reserved word in javascript, so it is best practice in your code to do:

`future['return']`

```
instead of

future.return
```